# Ant Build kept on failing with no obvious reason

Tags: apache-flex, ant, build

Apologies if this sounds stupid, It has really given me a hell of a time. I tried to build a flex project using Antennae with ant installed which is under svn versioning. each time I run ant build it goes on building all the libraries and application but always come up with /n

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/Antennae/tools/build-master-targets.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/Antennae/tools/build-common-tasks.xml:279: The following error occurred while executing this line: /home/user/Antennae/tools/build-common-targets.xml:214: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/Antennae/tools/build-common-tasks.xml:95: Java returned: 30
Total time: 4 minutes 20 seconds
```

I have got no clue what the error means as the mentioned codes/ files were not altered by me.

Comment: those are some pretty hairy ant files... it's dying at a sub-ant in a macrodef.  It would be helpful to see the verbose output.  run ant -v

Comment: @thekbb It came up with almost 500 lines of codes/reports. I am not sure i should dump all those reports here. but with the same BUILD FAILED earlier shown above.

Comment: Try posting all your Ant build files and `ant -v` output to an online pastebin and post the link. You can also use gist.github.com to post it. Also post the code snippet around line 95 in build-common-tasks.xml here.

Comment: **line 95 starts from here** `${flex.frameworks.dir}" /> <br  />
                <arg value="-load-config=@{config}" />  
                <arg value="-source-path=@{src.dir}" />  
                <arg value="-include-sources=@{src.dir}" />  
                <arg value="-output=@{dest}" />  
            </java>`

Comment: Ahaha! Praise God!  I have been able to build successfully now. thanks for all your helps. The problem was the sdk was not including data-visualisation and automation properly (or rather I did not do the configuration well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the sdk was not including data-visualisation and automation properly (or rather I did not do the configuration well).